# Java Netbeans Conexion a Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: dbconnection.DBConnection.executeUpdate
> at dbconnection.DBConnection.(DBConnection.java:23)
> at dbconnection.DBConnection.main(DBConnection.java:61)
> C:\Users\JorgeSotoSolis\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 13 seconds)

Mi código es:

```
package dbconnection;

import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnection {


 Connection conn = null;
 Statement st = null;
 ResultSet rs = null;

public DBConnection(){
    
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); 
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/pedidos", "postgres", "1234");
        
        st = conn.createStatement();
        
        st= executeUpdate("insert into clientes (clienteid, cedula_ruc, nombrecia, nombrecontacto, direccioncli)"
        +"values (11, '123456','Mi NEGOCIO','VERONICA VELA','Domicilio Desconocido')");
        
    
        
        
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        
    }
    
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
   
    
    new DBConnection();
}





}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tiene toda la pinta de ser un error de NetBeans. Prueba ir a las propiedades del proyecto, ir a la sección `Build -> Compiling` y desmarcar la opción "Compile on save".

Esto pasa porque unos IDE (como NetBeans) permiten correr el código inculso si algunas clases no se pueden compilar. En tiempo de ejecución, si entras a esa clase, te sale esta excepción que nos muestras. El IDE tiene una versión en caché, que no coincide necesariamente con la versión actual del código en tu editor.

Después de este cambio, es posible que necesites hacer un clean build y forzar si es el caso, que se recompile todo.

Si persiste, habría que borrar el caché a mano pero ya es una idea no tan buena.

Comment: now i have a different error message

Comment: ant -f C:\\Users\\JorgeSotoSolis\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\DBConnection -Djavac.includes=dbconnection/DBConnection.java -Dnb.internal.action.name=run.single -Drun.class=dbconnection.DBConnection run-single
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\JorgeSotoSolis\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DBConnection\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\JorgeSotoSolis\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DBConnection\build\built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\JorgeSotoSolis\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DBConnection\build\classes

Comment: C:\Users\JorgeSotoSolis\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DBConnection\nbproject\build-impl.xml:953: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\JorgeSotoSolis\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DBConnection\nbproject\build-impl.xml:270: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Creo que ya se que fue el error, es un typo, en una sentencia puse st = executeUpdate en lugar de poner st.executeUpdate.

Comment: Diferente problema? Diferente pregunta (para la próxima). Si la respuesta resolvió tu problema, puedes marcarla como aceptada.